# How can I calculate a new column depending of the value from my column? I need to create string chains to create my new column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, function, calculated-columns, string-concatenation

I have a column that has a number value (15, ..., 28, etc) called 'big', but depending on this number it should sum the columns with 5 previous numbers columns names, I mean something like...

| big | c15 | c16 | c17 | ... | c27 | c28 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| 21 | 1 | 1 | 0 | ... | 1 | 1 |
| ... | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| 25 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 |

So, depending on the "big" column, for example, 25, my new column should sum 'c24'+'c23'+'c22'+'c21'+'c20' and the result must be calculated in the new column name.

I have tried several movements but it doesn't works. I show my code below:

```
def test_fun(df):
    if (df['big'] > 19).all():
        pc = []
        for i in range(1,6):
            x = 'c' + (df['big'] - i).apply(str)
            pc.append(x)
        y = df[pc].sum(axis = 1)
        return y
    elif (df['big'] == 19).all():
        pc = []
        for i in range(1,5):
            x = 'c' + (df['big'] - i).apply(str)
            pc.append(x)
        y = df[pc].sum(axis = 1)
        return y
    elif (df['big'] == 18).all():
        pc = []
        for i in range(1,4):
            x = 'c' + (df['big'] - i).apply(str)
            pc.append(x)
        y = df[pc].sum(axis = 1)
        return y
    else:
        pc = []
        for i in range(1,3):
            x = 'c' + (df['big'] - i).apply(str)
            pc.append(x)
        y = df[pc].sum(axis = 1)
        return y

df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: test_fun(df), axis = 1)
```

I added several conditions due to actually my table is beginning from c15 to c28 column, but it will be increasing during time.

Finally, when I use the function `df.apply()` to apply my function by row I had been having several errors during my trials. Some of them like:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

that's what I added `.all()` in my `if, elif, else` conditions. Even...

```
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index  'c27', 'c27', ...,\n   ('c26', 'c26',...  dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Do you know what I should be probably doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure - if you value in `big` is `n` you'll need to calculate `col(n-1)+col(n-2)...+col(n-5)`)

Comment: you want row wise or column wise sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

```
def get_big(series):
    n = series["big"]
    indices = ["c%s" % i for i in range(n-1, n-6, -1)]
    indices = series.index.intersection(indices)
    return series[indices].sum()

df.apply(get_big, axis=1)
```

Sample data

```
   c20  c21  c22  c23  c24  c25  c26  c27  c28  c29  big
0    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    0   21
1    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0   28
2    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0   20
3    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1   20
4    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0   23
5    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0   25
6    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0   23
7    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1   20
8    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1   26
9    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1   25
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    0
8    3
9    2
dtype: int64
```